# AWS Athena: partition table for S3 bucket with non-standard file structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, database-partitioning

I'm very new to Athena and I'm having a little bit of hard time understanding how partitioning works and if it can work for me.

I have files in S3 in the following format:
`path/to/files/YYYYmmDDTHHMMSSZ_<id>.json`

For example:

```
path/to/files/20191208T130435Z_265901.json
path/to/files/20191212T132019Z_266406.json
path/to/files/20191216T102909Z_266975.json
path/to/files/20191226T095326Z_268789.json
path/to/files/20191226T103749Z_268798.json
path/to/files/20191226T110113Z_268802.json
path/to/files/20191229T182902Z_269391.json
path/to/files/20191230T041315Z_269481.json
path/to/files/20200101T200007Z_269935.json
...
```

I understand that this does not follow the guidelines for correct hive-style partitioning, but I'm not the owner of the data, so this cannot change.

**My question is:** Is there any way to specify a monthly partition to such a structure?

I'm reading [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-setting-up.html) but I'm not sure if and how it applies to my case.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after reading the documentation more carefully, I think the answer is "no". If I had a delimiter ("/") after "YYYYmmDD", then this would be possible by partition projection, but since there is not, this cannot happen either.

It seems there is no other way as the workaround @Alex has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-process your data, and rename them, to have proper directory structure.

For ex:

1. Object uploaded
2. Send S3 PUT event to lambda (setup it carefully to not interfere with step 3)
3. Copy+delete this object to correct directory structure.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a workaround that I would rather avoid. So, to answer my question, you think the answer is "no"? No way to create Athena partitions the way the data is stored right now?

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately we can partition just based on / parts of path.

Comment: Got it, I also confirmed this from the documentation, thank you